# Creating acknowledgements page like abstract has same page number

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, page-numbering, abstract

I am using `hyperref` and the `report` document class.

To create an acknowledgements page that looks like the abstract I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{My Title}
\author{Matt}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\maketitle

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
an abstract
\end{abstract}


\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}

\begin{abstract}
 I would like to thank blablabla
\end{abstract}
\newpage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

But in my table of contents it labels the abstract and acknowledgements page with the same page number, (both page `i`)

How can I make these "abstracts" be treated as separate pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the option `notitlepage` to the document class:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
```

and then rewrite the code you've posted as

```
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
an abstract
\end{abstract}


\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}

\begin{abstract}
 I would like to thank blablabla
\end{abstract}
```

### EDIT

With your corrected MWE and your comments, try this way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{My Title}
\author{Matt}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\null\vfill
\setcounter{page}{1}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
an abstract
\end{abstract}
\vskip4cm\vfill

\newpage
\null\vfill
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
 I would like to thank blablabla
\end{abstract}
\vskip4cm\vfill

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Note that I've added `\vskip4cm` for a matter of aesthetics, you can reduce it or change it to `\null`.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem and its pretty much good enough for me. However, just to note the abstract is created inside the titlepage environment, so switching to notitlepage changes its vertical alignment. If there's anyway to fix that please let me know. Other than that I'm satisfied

Comment: Your MWE lacks the preamble and other things you might have at the beginning of the document, so I've tried to guess a bit... Do you mean that you want the `abstract` in the title page?

Comment: sorry I'm new to SE. I've edited my first post to a mwe. What I meant is that when you change the environment to "notitlepage" the abstract is no longer almost halfway down the page. It now appears right at the top.

Comment: I accidentally just edited your post to my mwe. Hopefully the "peer review" realises I'm new and doesn't change your solution.

Comment: Happy if it helps :-)